# How to implement CCMotionStreak After CCsprite move?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

hello friend i want to implement MotionStreak after Sprite move from one to another point.when it move then its display shadow (MotionStreak). how can i implement it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you take a sprite in init method which move on Screen

```
torpedoOne = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Button1.png"];
        torpedoOne.position = ccp(0,0);
        [self addChild:torpedoOne z:2];
```

Now take CCMotionStreak in init method

```
 streak = [CCMotionStreak streakWithFade:1.7f minSeg:5 width:10 color:ccWHITE textureFilename:@"Button1.png"];
    streak.position =torpedoOne.position;
[self addChild:streak z:2];
```

Action of SpriteMove

```
   id actionMove = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:2.0
                                        position:ccp(320, 320)];
    [torpedoOne runAction:[CCSequence actions:actionMove, nil]];
```

Update sprite position

```
[self schedule:@selector(doStep:)];
```

Update Method

```
- (void)doStep:(ccTime)delta
{
    //update the position
    [streak setPosition:torpedoOne.position];
}
```